# Inserting double quotes and single quotes not on keyboard in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have trying to insert the double quotes other than keyboard

for ex :

statement :  Ashley is studying for an exam. During her review, she notes that “semantic” denotes “meaning” and thinks about how this relates to semantic memory. A second review showed her that

It get converted to following after being inserted into mysql database:

Ashley is studying for an exam. During her review, she notes that â€œsemanticâ€ denotes â€œmeaningâ€ and thinks about how this relates to semantic memory. A

I have converted all the tables and database into utf-8 collation and also used meta tag for utf-8 but with no success. Can someone identify the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the following method: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always do it like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db');
$cod = $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Set the encoding
```

This code was working for me (just now):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ab</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>

<body>
<?
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
$cod = $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO `test`(`string`) VALUES ('".addslashes("“teststring“")."')");
$result = $db->query("SELECT `string` FROM `test` WHERE string='".addslashes("“teststring“")."'");

$result= $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['string'];

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually I am posting data via ajax and I have run mysql_query("set names 'utf8'") before the insertion query but still with no success

Comment: Have you also tried it with the `htmlspecialchars();` function?

Comment: Yes its not making any difference

Comment: What's your value in the tab `Operations` in the section `collation`? Mine is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Sorry It not making any difference

Comment: the double quotes which I am using are not from keyboard they are  “

Comment: It is working for also with the “! To add the backslashes automatically use the `addslashes()`. That you see what I mean I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you it worked getting inserted properly but not displaying properly in html

Comment: What do you mean with displaying not properly in html?

Comment: “! getting converted to � in html

Comment: I've updated my post showing my full code (it is still working). Perhaps something with the `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`is wrong?